# Simplifying UPDATE for tables representing power sets

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have 2 tables that I'm trying to use to perform some calculations. My first (which is basically a power set of 'ABC' and not including NONE) table looks like this:

```
TABLE: test3
rowID    v1      v2      v3      combo    initialValue
1        NULL    NULL    M170_4  C        NULL
2        NULL    M170_3  NULL    B        NULL
3        NULL    M170_3  M170_4  BC       NULL
4        M170_2  NULL    NULL    A        NULL
5        M170_2  NULL    M170_4  AC       NULL
6        M170_2  M170_3  NULL    AB       NULL
7        M170_2  M170_3  M170_4  ABC      NULL
```

I need to update the `initialValue` column for each row.

I have another table like this:

```
TABLE: my_data_db
ID      WEIGHT    v1      v2      v3
1       1.34      0.10    NULL    NULL
2       0.53      0.75    NULL    0.75
3       1.24      0.25    0.10    0.25
4       0.95      NULL    1.00    0.10
5       0.72      0.75    NULL    0.10
6       0.145     1.00    1.00    0.75
...
AND SO ON
```

For each row in `test3` I need to calculate the sum of the product of the corresponding rows in `my_data_db` like so:

```
DECLARE @total FLOAT
SET @total = 4898.947426

UPDATE test3 SET initialValue = 
(
    SELECT SUM(v3 * WEIGHT / @total) FROM my_data_db
)
WHERE combo = 'C'

UPDATE test3 SET initialValue = 
(
    SELECT SUM(v2 * WEIGHT / @total) FROM my_data_db
)
WHERE combo = 'B'

UPDATE test3 SET initialValue = 
(
    SELECT SUM(v2 * v3 * WEIGHT / @total) FROM my_data_db
)
WHERE combo = 'BC'


UPDATE test3 SET initialValue = 
(
    SELECT SUM(v1 * WEIGHT / @total) FROM my_data_db
)
WHERE combo = 'A'

UPDATE test3 SET initialValue = 
(
    SELECT SUM(v1 * v2 * WEIGHT / @total) FROM my_data_db
)
WHERE combo = 'AB'

UPDATE test3 SET initialValue = 
(
    SELECT SUM(v1 * v3 * WEIGHT / @total) FROM my_data_db
)
WHERE combo = 'AC'

UPDATE test3 SET initialValue = 
(
    SELECT SUM(v1 * v2 * v3 * WEIGHT / @total) FROM my_data_db
)
WHERE combo = 'ABC'
```

What I can't figure out is how to simplify my `UPDATE`s so I don't have to have one update per row. My `UPDATE` code above, while ugly, isn't too much work, but the real problem is that I'll have tables similar to `test3` that have over a million rows, all with unique combinations of their respective columns. Also, I'd like to not use a`CURSOR` or `WHILE` loop if it's not necessary. My solution using a `CURSOR` (see previous post mentioned below) doesn't scale when my power set tables get huge.

Thanks.

*(NOTE: This is a follow up of: [Avoiding cursors to update many records using a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9640504/1177191))*

Comment: If you have over a million rows - do you really have queries that return all of these rows? Have you considered performing the calculations during querying rather than as a fixed update? (A stored calculation is always a potential source of errors)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I'm not sure I understand your question, but for the tables that can be up to 1 million rows, I have one table that's a template that I copy into a new table and perform some basic replacements (the initial values of v1, v2, etc. aren't as they are above - they'll always be different for each table). That particular part only takes a few seconds. As to your other point about the calculations: Yes. In this case they must be stored in the table for something that I need to do with them later.

Comment: I'm asking - are you sure that this calculation has to be done once, for all of these rows - or could it be reasonable to perform this calculation at query time, for those rows that are actually being returned?

Comment: Every single row has to be calculated always every time for every table like this. Always.

Comment: I would re-emphasize - *storing* calculations that are based on other data isn't (generally) how you should work with a database.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Again. I have no choice here. I can't use a computed column because the computation for each field of each is different - which is the whole point of my question really. Plus, the data in my_data_db will never change. Ever. It's created from a larger master table of data (that also will probably never change). If you know of a way to make this a computed column that can variably compute based on the values in `test3` I'd love some advice.

Comment: What does *unique combinations of columns* mean? In particular, does it mean that there will always be only one row per table where, say, `v1` and `v3` are not NULL, regardless of the actual values stored in those two columns? In other words, do the actual (non-NULL) values of `v1` through `vN` in a `test3`-like table matter in these calculations?

Comment: @AndriyM: That's basically correct. Each row is a unique combination of the values contained in `v1` through `vN`. And the actual values in the `v` columns in `test3` don't really mean anything at this point. They used to refer to the original columns that I pulled in the `vN` column values in `my_data_db`. To put it another way, the columns in `my_data_db` could be named `M170_2` instead of `v1`, `M170_3` instead of `v2`, etc. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's what I wanted to know.

Comment: @AndriyM: Your answer is great! Thanks so much. I learned a lot from your cord, too. I expanded the for a table w/ 20 `vN` columns (which should be the maximum I'd ever have) and it took about 3 1/2 minutes to run in SQL Server Mgmt Studio. Any advice on making it run faster or am I asking too much? Thanks again.

Comment: @tptcat: No, I don't think you are asking too much, but I'm not sure if I can suggest something useful in this situation. I might try making the temporary `keyN` columns (both sets) created in the query, static computed columns and indexing them. (The query should then be rid of the first two CTEs, and the last CTE should read directly from the tables.) I.e. my guess is, it is slow because of the join based on dynamically computed columns, but if they were static, the query might run faster. I repeat, I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @AndriyM Appreciate the advice! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does the same calculations as your series of updates, but using a single statement. You can see that the `combo` column is not used here. Instead, a new set of columns is generated for each of the two tables. The new columns take part both in joining the tables and in the calculations.

```
;
WITH
  test3_with_keys AS (
    SELECT
      RowID,
      key1 = CASE WHEN v1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
      key2 = CASE WHEN v2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
      key3 = CASE WHEN v3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    FROM @test3
  ),
  my_data_db_with_keys AS (
    SELECT
      WEIGHT,
      v1,
      v2,
      v3,
      key1 = CASE WHEN v1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
      key2 = CASE WHEN v2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
      key3 = CASE WHEN v3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    FROM @my_data_db
  ),
  calculated AS (
    SELECT
      t.RowID,
      initialValue = SUM(
        ISNULL(NULLIF(t.key1, 0) * d.v1, 1) *
        ISNULL(NULLIF(t.key2, 0) * d.v2, 1) *
        ISNULL(NULLIF(t.key3, 0) * d.v3, 1) *
        d.WEIGHT / @total
      )
    FROM test3_with_keys t
      INNER JOIN my_data_db_with_keys d ON t.key1 <= d.key1
                                       AND t.key2 <= d.key2
                                       AND t.key3 <= d.key3
    GROUP BY
      t.rowID
  )
UPDATE test3
SET initialValue = c.initialValue
FROM calculated c
WHERE test3.RowID = c.RowID;
```

Note: it is assumed that `RowID` values are unique.